# is_base_of in a template parameter - class does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Just wondering why I can't use is_base_of in a C++ template argument like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct base
{
};

struct derived : public base
{
    int value;
};




template<class A, class B, bool isbaseof = std::is_base_of<A,B>::value> myclass
{
    void foo() {
        cout << "Generic..";
    }
};

template<class A, class B> myclass<A,B,true>
{
    void foo() {
        cout << "A is not base of B";
    }
};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp:17:73: error: ‘myclass’ does not name a type
 template<class A, class B, bool isbaseof = std::is_base_of<A,B>::value> myclass
```

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the class key:

```
   template<class A, class B, bool isbaseof = std::is_base_of<A, B>::value>
   struct myclass
// ^^^^^^
```

(The class key can be any of `class`, `struct` or `union`.)

Comment: And in the partial specialization as well: `template<class A, class B> struct myclass<A,B,true>`.

Comment: Thanks! The error was quite ambiguous to me.. I'm definitely tired.